# Java Immutables Polymorphism - how to make generated class extend another class?

Tags: java, immutables-library

I'm using the `immutables` library to create immutable objects from interfaces. However, I can't find a way to make generated classes extend one another in order to make them polymorphic.

Consider this code:

```
@Value.Immutable
@ImmutableStyle
@JsonSerialize
public interface AbstractAdvert {

    String getAdvertName();

    @Nullable
    String getAdvertRef();

    AdvertPrice getPrice();

    AdvertProvider getProvider();

    @Value.Default
    default Boolean getBillsIncluded() {
        return false;
    }

    @Value.Immutable
    @ImmutableStyle
    @JsonSerialize
    interface AbstractStudioAdvert extends AbstractAdvert {

    }
}
```

This will generate two classes: `Advert` and `StudioAdvert`.

I'd like to have methods elsewhere that take `List<Advert>` as a parameter but it also accepts `List<StudioAdvert>` hence I need the polymorphism here.

**TLDR:** The above code doesn't make generated `StudioAdvert` extend `Advert`. I'd like them to have that relationship though.

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

In my use case, let's say I have a `List<StudioAdvert>` and a `List<RoomAdvert>` that I would like to pass to the same function for processing. The following method does not work at the moment if I use `List<Advert>` or `List<AbstractAdvert>` as method's parameter.

```
public static ProcessedResult processResult(List<AbstractAdvert> adverts) {
    ...
}
```

The issue is as below.
[image]

Comment: List<T extends AbstractAdvert> will work for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question on how you generate the code and/or how you use the builder/factory classes.

Comment: Why do you need `StudioAdvert` to extend `Advert`? Both of them extend `AbstractAdvert`, as does `AbstractStudioAdvert`. You can have a `List<AbstractAdvert>` and it will accept instances of both generated classes.

Comment: @Progman That code looks pretty complete and self-contained already.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Comment: @Thilo I have included more information in "EDIT 1" to show you that it doesn't work at the moment. The generated classes by `immutables` library do not have a relationship such that `StudioAdvert extends Advert`, but instead it has `StudioAdvert implements AbstractAdvert.AbstractStudioAdvert`.

Comment: @Progman the first link answered my question - thanks. I've got some learning to do haha.